# Append Random Number to URL in Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, formstack

I am trying to append a random number Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);

To an embedded Formstack Form such as this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://brynhowlett.formstack.com/forms/js.php/starbucks_orders__copy&"></script>
```

Int needs to go at the end right after the "&".  I almost had it but keep messing up. I just need a push in the right directions.

Also I need it to be all inline.  So I guess I would add the following above it the embedded form.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
```

JS goes here

```
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give us some code please and give use more explanation ?

Comment: Sorry just did forgot to put 4 spaces before html

Comment: Is it normal that you have a `&` in your script url and not a `?` ?

Comment: This is easy to do when calling the url your web page is on but I am trying to either getElementById or Tag.  Then manipulate it and return the URL with the Random Number

Comment: Yea because Formstack requires the & rather than the ?.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `document.open()` , `document.write()` , `document.close()`

```html
<script>
  document.open();
  document.write("<script src=https://brynhowlett.formstack.com/forms/js.php/starbucks_orders__copy&" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1) + "><\/script>");
  document.close();
</script>
<body>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think that is it because that is pulled directly from w3schools.com

Comment: @BHCOM Receving error at `console` when attempt to create `script` element and append to `document` , or change `<script>` element `src` : `Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened. `

Comment: I think it is possible. I have seen it done in another example but can't find that example and it was a little different.